# Anaconda fails to launch my Jupyter because of launch error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I tried to launch the Jupyter notebook from Anaconda and I am getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 44, in 
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in 
from .environment import Environment

File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in 
from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING

File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 3, in 
from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401

File "C:\Users\saiki\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\filters.py", line 13, in 
from markupsafe import soft_unicode

ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py)
```

**It was working properly until I installed pandas-profiling library in my Anaconda Powershell prompt.**

*How to rectify this?*

Answer (score 2):

I found such an issue on github: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661

Downgrading markupsafe to 2.0.1 fixes the issue on my side.

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

But doing that raises another error which has been mentioned as another comment in this post, quote:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. anaconda-project 0.10.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed. cookiecutter 1.7.2 requires MarkupSafe<2.0.0, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible. `

Comment: @SaiKishore I received the same error after installing markupsafe 2.0.1, but  Anaconda is launching properly.